# Industrial mechanism for creating a profile for each angularjs menu item

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, menu, web

I'm creating a web site using spring boot and `AngularJS`, There is a side menu which creates dynamically and each menu item represents a person. When a user clicks a menu item, the profile of the person of that particular menu item should be displayed. I have created a template page for the profile and I want to know what is the mechanism of using this same profile page with the details of the person in the clicked menu item ? 
[image: Like below Image]

Here is the code for the dynamic menu

```
 <md-list>                                
    <a ng-repeat="x in menuItems" href="{{x.href}}">{{x.name}}</a>
 </md-list>
```

menuItems array

```
$scope.menuItems = [ {href: '#/menu1', name: "Menu Item 1"},
                     {href: '#/menu2', name: "Menu Item 2"},
                     {href: '#/menu3', name: "Menu Item 3"},
                     {href: '#/menu4', name: "Menu Item 4"},
                     {href: '#/menu5', name: "Menu Item 5"} ];
```

Angularjs route provider

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when("/menu1", {
                templateUrl: "template.html"
            })
            .when("/menu2", {
                templateUrl: "template.html"
            })
            .when("/menu3", {
                templateUrl: "template.html"
            })
            .when("/menu4", {
                templateUrl: "template.html"
            })
            .when("/menu5", {
                templateUrl: "template.html"
            });
})
```

Comment: are you use ui-router ?

Comment: @AhmedMostafa yes, I have used ui-routers. and I have edited my question with the code snippets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resolve` property in the $routeProvider.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/menu1", {
            templateUrl: "template.html"
            controller: "ProfilePageController"
            resolve: {
                profile: function(ProfileService) {
                    return ProfileService.getProfile(1)
                }
            }
        })
        .when("/menu2", {
            templateUrl: "template.html"
            controller: "ProfilePageController"
            resolve: {
                profile: function(ProfileService) {
                    return ProfileService.getProfile(2)
                }
            }
        })
        .when("/menu3", {
            templateUrl: "template.html"
            controller: "ProfilePageController"
            resolve: {
                profile: function(ProfileService) {
                    return ProfileService.getProfile(3)
                }
            }
        });
})
```

Then in your service:

```
app.factory("ProfileService", function() {
    return {
        getProfile: function(id) {
            // Fetch the profile
            return profile;
        }
    }
});
```

Now in your controller you need to inject the resolve:

```
app.controller("ProfilePageController", function (profile) {
   $scope.profile = profile; 
});
```

Comment: Hi @jifama, Thank you for your answer and it seems that it suits to my scenario. I'll check with my code and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

but this is not ui-router this is ngRoute any way u must change the route to be one route not like what you mad here.

```
 $routeProvider
    .when("/menu/:id", { // :id => my dynamic param for the route
        templateUrl: "template.html"
        controller: "ProfilePageController"
        resolve: {
            profile: function(ProfileService , $routeParams ) {
                // $routeParams.id => get the route param that called :id
                return ProfileService.getProfile($routeParams.id);
            }
        }
    })
```